# When I delete a particular row of the tableview in Xamarin.iOS . the tableview become what it was before.

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am working in xamarin.ios .Below attached with the code

```
public override void CommitEditingStyle (UITableView tableView,UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath){

      switch (editingStyle) {
             case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete:
             // delete the row from the table
             tableView.DeleteRows (new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
             break;
             case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None:
             break;
}}
```

It works when I swipe to delete.Hovever,when I push a new ViewController and come back .There is no change.

I am new in iOS. Hopefully somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just refreshed the interface. which is not enough .
use the code

```
    // remove the item from the underlying data source
    tableItems.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
    // delete the row from the table
    tableView.DeleteRows (new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
```

At the same time, you should delete the corresponding data from the data source.

Comment: when you come back ,the tableview will be reloadData. The datasource are from such as an arrayList.So,you should delete the corresponding data.Otherwise, even if you delete a row, it will resume after reloading.

Comment: I still do not quite understand, but it works.  I couldn’t have done it without you